# Export original HEIC/HEVC files to iOS app

Tags: ios, photos, file-conversion

I am trying to transfer the original HEIC/HEVC encoded media files from the iOS app to another app (namely, Readdle's Documents app). I would like to do this *without* converting the files.

Transferring the original files is possible using AirDrop if you enable [an iOS setting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349858/airdrop-or-export-multiple-original-quality-videos-from-ios-photos-app). However, I am trying to find a way to get the original file *on-device* without using a Mac or a PC.